# How to project 2d laser scanner data in world co-ordinate system

Tags: python, coordinates, robotics, coordinate-transformation, lidar

I have small tank drive robot which has a rplidar a1 mounted on it. The robot has a raspberry pi on board.
I am working on making a small arena with cardboard obstacles.
I can find the pose(x,y,heading) of the robot using aruco markers and a celling mounted  downward looking webcam.
My x axis is aligned with magnetic north and y axis aligned along west and z axis is upward(prolly wont need it).

Now if i drive robot and look at the laser scans, it looks like the robot always at the center of the co-ordinate system and it looks like the robot is stationary and the world is moving

But i want to display a map using the laser scan data and the robot pose where the world is stationary and the robot is moving just like as seen in google maps(AS AN ANALOGY,NOT LIKE THE WHOLE ACTUAL SOFTWARE)

I want to only use the current laser scan and the current location of the robot and not any previous pose or scan data and i am aware it might make the map look a little glitchy and it is okay with me.
Given a robot pose (rx, ry, heading) and a point (x, y) in the
       scanner's coordinate system,how can i return the point's coordinates in the
       world coordinate system.

Here is the code for aruco marker-

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
import sys, time, math
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

#--- Define Tag
id_to_find  = 1
marker_size  = 6.4#- [cm]



# Checks if a matrix is a valid rotation matrix.
def isRotationMatrix(R):
    Rt = np.transpose(R)
    shouldBeIdentity = np.dot(Rt, R)
    I = np.identity(3, dtype=R.dtype)
    n = np.linalg.norm(I - shouldBeIdentity)
    return n < 1e-6


# Calculates rotation matrix to euler angles
# The result is the same as MATLAB except the order
# of the euler angles ( x and z are swapped ).
def rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R):
    assert (isRotationMatrix(R))

    sy = math.sqrt(R[0, 0] * R[0, 0] + R[1, 0] * R[1, 0])

   singular = sy < 1e-6

    if not singular:
        x = math.atan2(R[2, 1], R[2, 2])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2, 0], sy)
        z = math.atan2(R[1, 0], R[0, 0])
    else:
        x = math.atan2(-R[1, 2], R[1, 1])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2, 0], sy)
        z = 0

    return np.array([x, y, z])




    #--- Get the camera calibration path
    calib_path  = ""
    camera_matrix   = np.loadtxt(calib_path+'cameraMatrix.txt', delimiter=',')
    camera_distortion   = np.loadtxt(calib_path+'cameraDistortion.txt', delimiter=',')

    #--- 180 deg rotation matrix around the x axis
    R_flip  = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.float32)
    R_flip[0,0] = 1.0
    R_flip[1,1] =-1.0
    R_flip[2,2] =-1.0

    #--- Define the aruco dictionary
    aruco_dict  = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL)
    parameters  = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    #--- Capture the videocamera (this may also be a video or a picture)
    #-- Set the camera size as the one it was calibrated with
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

    #-- Font for the text in the image
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

    while True:

        #-- Read the camera frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        #-- Convert in gray scale
        gray    = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #-- remember, OpenCV stores color images                       
in Blue, Green, Red

    #-- Find all the aruco markers in the image
    corners, ids, rejected = aruco.detectMarkers(image=gray, dictionary=aruco_dict, 
parameters=parameters,
                          cameraMatrix=camera_matrix, distCoeff=camera_distortion)

if ids is not None:# and ids[0] == id_to_find:

    #-- ret = [rvec, tvec, ?]
    #-- array of rotation and position of each marker in camera frame
    #-- rvec = [[rvec_1], [rvec_2], ...]    attitude of the marker respect to camera frame
    #-- tvec = [[tvec_1], [tvec_2], ...]    position of the marker in camera frame
    for cr in corners:
        print('IDS FOUND =' + str(len(corners)))
        #print(corners)
        ret = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(cr, marker_size, camera_matrix, camera_distortion)
        #-- Unpack the output, get only the first
        rvec, tvec = ret[0][0,0,:], ret[1][0,0,:]
        #-- Draw the detected marker and put a reference frame over it
        aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners)
        aruco.drawAxis(frame, camera_matrix, camera_distortion, rvec, tvec, 10)
        #-- Print the tag position in camera frame
        str_position = "MARKER Position x=%4.0f  y=%4.0f  z=%4.0f"%(tvec[0], -tvec[1], tvec[2])
        cv2.putText(frame, str_position, (0, 100), font, 1, (0, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if key == ord('q'):
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

here is the code for laser scanner data -

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
'''Animates distances and measurment quality'''
from rplidar import RPLidar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

PORT_NAME = 'COM18'
DMAX = 4000
IMIN = 0
IMAX = 50

def update_line(num, iterator, line):
    scan = next(iterator)
    offsets = np.array([(np.radians(meas[1]), meas[2]) for meas in scan])
    line.set_offsets(offsets)
    intens = np.array([meas[0] for meas in scan])
    line.set_array(intens)
    return line,

def run():
    lidar = RPLidar(PORT_NAME)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
    line = ax.scatter([0, 0], [0, 0], s=5, c=[IMIN, IMAX],
                           cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, lw=0)
    ax.set_rmax(DMAX)
    ax.grid(True)

    iterator = lidar.iter_scans()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line,
        fargs=(iterator, line), interval=50)
    plt.show()
    lidar.stop()
    lidar.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use ROS, which has rplidar driver and SLAM package?

Comment: Can't install  ROS with raspbian strech.